# "a list with" or "a list of"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which word would you use after list here, "with" or "of"?

> Make a list of all the verbs you know.

or

> Make a list with all the verbs you know.

Comment: Both are idiomatic in American English though I prefer “of.”

Comment: Only _of_ seems idiomatic to me as a British English speaker.

Comment: I find *of* more common and idiomatic in American English too.  *"I have here in my hand a list of two hundred and five people that were known to the Secretary of State as being members of the Communist Party..."*

Comment: They are not synonymous, because *list with* could be used to describe other properties of the list. For example, “make a list with three antonyms”

Comment: Wouldn't that be 'big-small, short-tall, fat-skinny' also a list of three antonyms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which word would you use after list

### list of

We conventionally make a **list *of*** items.

So ***of*** should always be your first choice of preposition after **list**.

---

We may also:

- make a list *including* certain items

And, (with approximately the same meaning as above):

- make a list *with* certain items

though this would be less common than *including*.

---

Using *list including* or *list with* introduces a *qualifying feature* of the list.

You would still need to know what the **main determining feature** of the list is.

So:

- Make a list with at least six Mediterranean countries

is a bit baffling. We know it should include six Mediterranean countries (that's a *qualifying* feature) but what determines the rest of the list? It's not yet clear what we're making a **list of**.

Whereas:

- Make a list of all the European countries you know, *including* at least six Mediterranean countries

is much clearer. Now we have the same qualifying feature, but the main determining feature is also clarified.